# Haskell parser combinator - do notation

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, do-notation

I was reading a tutorial regarding building a parser combinator library and i came across a method which i don't quite understand.

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {parse :: String -> [(a,String)]}

chainl :: Parser a -> Parser (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Parser a
chainl p op a = (p `chainl1` op) <|> return a

chainl1 :: Parser a -> Parser (a -> a -> a) -> Parser a
p `chainl1` op = do {a <- p; rest a}
  where rest a = (do f <- op
                     b <- p
                     rest (f a b))
                 <|> return a

bind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
bind p f = Parser $ \s -> concatMap (\(a, s') -> parse (f a) s') $ parse p s
```

the `bind` is the implementation of the `(>>=)` operator.  I don't quite get how the `chainl1` function works. From what I can see you extract `f` from `op` and then you apply it to `f a b` and you recurse, however I do not get how you extract a function from the parser when it should return a list of tuples?

Comment: Look at the type for `chainl`. The second argument, `op`, is a `Parser (a -> a -> a)`, which *is* a parser that produces a function.

Comment: You do not 'extract' the function, the `do` notation is sugar for uses of `>>=` in which you can access the result of a `Parser` within another `Parser`. The only way to actually get something of type `a` out of `Parser a` is to apply the function to a string (and hope the list is non-empty), but you do not need to do this (and should not) to manipulate parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at the definition of `Parser`:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {parse :: String -> [(a,String)]}`
```

A `Parser a` is really just a wrapper around a function (that we can run later with `parse`) that takes a `String` and returns a list of pairs, where each pair contains an `a` encountered when processing the string, along with the rest of the string that remains to be processed.

Now look at the part of the code in `chainl1` that's confusing you: the part where you extract `f` from `op`:

```
f <- op
```

You remarked: "I do not get how you extract a function from the parser when it should return a list of tuples."

It's true that when we *run* a `Parser a` with a string (using `parse`), we get a list of type `[(a,String)]` as a result. But this code does not say `parse op s`. Rather, we are using `bind` here (with the do-notation syntactic sugar). The problem is that you're thinking about the definition of the `Parser` datatype, but you're not thinking much about what `bind` specifically does.

Let's look at what `bind` is doing in the `Parser` monad a bit more carefully.

```
bind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
bind p f = Parser $ \s -> concatMap (\(a, s') -> parse (f a) s') $ parse p s
```

What does `p >>= f` do? It returns a `Parser` that, when given a string `s`, does the following: First, it *runs* parser `p` with the string to be parsed, `s`. This, as you correctly noted, returns a list of type `[(a, String)]`: i.e. a list of the values of type `a` encountered, along with the string that remained after each value was encountered. Then it takes this list of pairs and applies a function to each pair. Specifically, each `(a, s')` pair in this list is transformed by (1) applying `f` to the parsed value `a` (`f a` returns a new parser), and then (2) *running* this new parser with the remaining string `s'`. This is a function from a tuple to a list of tuples: `(a, s') -> [(b, s'')]`... and since we're mapping this function over every tuple in the original list returned by `parse p s`, this ends up giving us a list of lists of tuples: `[[(b, s'')]]`. So we concatenate (or join) this list into a single list `[(b, s'')]`. All in all then, we have a function from `s` to `[(b, s'')]`, which we then wrap in a `Parser` newtype.

The crucial point is that when we say `f <- op`, or `op >>= \f -> ...` that assigns the name `f` to the values parsed by `op`, but `f` is not a list of tuples, b/c it is not the result of running `parse op s`.

In general, you'll see a lot of Haskell code that defines some datatype `SomeMonad a`, along with a `bind` method that hides a lot of the dirty details for you, and lets you get access to the `a` values you care about using do-notation like so: `a <- ma`. It may be instructive to look at the `State a` monad to see how `bind` passes around state behind the scenes for you. Similarly, here, when combining parsers, you care most about the values the parser is supposed to recognize... `bind` is hiding all the dirty work that involves the strings that remain upon recognizing a value of type `a`.

Comment: "that assigns the name f to the values parsed by op", what do you mean by this, is this not the list of tuples? I am slightly confused

Comment: No it's not the list of tuples. Since `op` is of type `Parser (a  -> a -> a)`, `f` is a fn (recognized by the parser) of type `a -> a -> a`.

If a parser `p` is of type `Parser Int`, then whenever I write `x <- p`, `x` will refer to some integer recognized by `p`. This is what we want it to refer to, right? This way we can easy combine multiple parsers into new parsers in arbitary ways that depend on the `x` value recognized by `p`. `bind` is hiding some complexity so that you don't have to deal with it / think about it.